# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, weblogic12c

I am trying to migrate my application from weblogic 10.3.5 to 12.2.1 when I am trying to download a file from the server location (in Oracle DB Server), I am facing below issue,I was able to download the file in with the previous version 10.3.5 below is the code sample which i am using.

JDK version I am using for this is jdk1.8.40.

```
public class TestFileVo{

private oracle.sql.BFILE binaryStatementFile;


public oracle.sql.BFILE getBinaryStatementFile() {
    return binaryStatementFile;
}

public void setBinaryStatementFile(oracle.sql.BFILE binaryStatementFile) {
    this.binaryStatementFile = binaryStatementFile;
}

}


queryString.append("select bfilename(?,?) from dual");

    ArrayList<TestFileVo> stmt = (ArrayList<TestFileVo>) jdbcTemplate.query(queryString.toString(), 
        new PreparedStatementSetter(){
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException{
                ps.setString(1, directiryString);
                ps.setString(2, fileName);
            }
        },
        new TransactionsMapper());
        TestFileVo test = stmt.get(0);
            if (!test.getBinaryStatementFile().fileExists()) {
                return false;
            }




            private class TransactionsMapper implements RowMapper<TestFileVo> {
            public TestFileVo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
            TestFileVo stmtFileVO = new TestFileVo();
            stmtFileVO.setBinaryStatementFile(((oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet)rs).getBFILE(1));   
            return stmtFileVO;
    }
}
```

Please find Exception stack trace below.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "oracle/sql/BFILE"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1065)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:998)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: I have fixed the issue by changing the class loader in weblogic.